# Como criar Séries Temporais usando Start e End no R?

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Estou tentando fazer uma série temporal com uma amostra de dados de 6 meses fazendo o seguinte:

```
compras = ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, start = c(2018,7), end = c(2019,1),
  frequency = 90)
```

Mas ao fazer um `plot(compras)` mostra uma série temporal incoerente com o período dos dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer a série temporal sem usar o `end` e ficou assim:

```
compras = ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, start = c(2018,7), frequency = 90)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também continua incoerente. O que devo fazer para apresentar uma série temporal que seja coerente com o período da minha amostra de dados?

Segue o `dput` da amostra:

```
dput(head(dados_dia, 50))
structure(list(DATA = structure(c(17731, 17732, 17733, 17734, 
17735, 17736, 17737, 17738, 17739, 17740, 17741, 17742, 17743, 
17744, 17745, 17746, 17747, 17748, 17749, 17750, 17751, 17752, 
17753, 17754, 17755, 17756, 17757, 17758, 17759, 17760, 17761, 
17762, 17763, 17764, 17765, 17766, 17767, 17768, 17769, 17770, 
17771, 17772, 17773, 17774, 17775, 17776, 17777, 17778, 17779, 
17780), class = "Date"), QTDE_COMPRAS = c(1831L, 1635L, 996L, 
889L, 2236L, 2145L, 2023L, 2036L, 1808L, 1056L, 951L, 2421L, 
2001L, 2011L, 1762L, 1364L, 865L, 778L, 2106L, 1816L, 1867L, 
1633L, 1501L, 892L, 736L, 2138L, 1971L, 1805L, 1814L, 1584L, 
874L, 756L, 2299L, 1855L, 2177L, 2096L, 1860L, 1032L, 917L, 2677L, 
2491L, 2444L, 2237L, 1933L, 1049L, 1035L, 2461L, 1929L, 1866L, 
1661L), VALOR_TOTAL = c(57652.18, 48584.93, 27914.92, 26742.56, 
72034.74, 67761.02, 62360.6, 61706.18, 51745.49, 27613.62, 26160.76, 
73334.99, 61721.56, 67054.88, 56929.74, 42995.77, 25133.76, 25312.76, 
72688.48, 62524.33, 62615.25, 55792.27, 47404.18, 26459.83, 23442.8, 
73834.73, 66589.4, 60754.27, 60277.49, 50185.86, 25684.23, 23432.76, 
78387.5, 62461.74, 72587.6, 66310.5, 56826.63, 29198.85, 27247.53, 
85714.93, 77316.9, 73900.85, 65110.36, 54674.84, 30347.08, 31843.1, 
81943.46, 63862.88, 60691.42, 49446.46)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `ts()` tem 4 argumentos principais.

O **primeiro** deles são os dados que serão transformados em série temporal. O **segundo** e o **terceiro** são o período inicial e final da série. Note que no exemplo passado o período final proposto não corresponde à data da última observação do `data.frame`.

O **quarto** argumento, por sua vez, diz respeito ao número de subperíodos existentes em um período. É com base nesse argumento que o `R` vai usar o segundo número passado em `start` e `end`.

Veja que no exemplo da pergunta o `R` achou que o segundo argumento de start (7) era relativo a um período que continha 90 subperíodos. Por isso ficava próximo a 2018.1, já que `7 / 90` é aproximadamente `0.08`.

Usando `365` no argumento `frequency`, informamos ao R que cada período (primeiro número de `start`) tem 365 subperíodos ou dias.

Uma opção é criar uma função que retorna a entrada esperada por `ts()` para `start` em séries diárias (como é o caso do exemplo).

```
data_ts_anual <- function(data) {
  ano <- lubridate::year(data)
  numero <- as.numeric(data - (lubridate::floor_date(data, "year") - 1))
  c(ano, numero)
}
```

E depois usar ele dentro da função `ts()`

```
compras <- ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, data_ts_anual(dados_dia$DATA[1]),
              data_ts_anual(dados_dia$DATA[nrow(dados_dia)]), 365)
plot(compras)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também é possível não informar o final de série (ajuda a evitar erros como o de acima) e deixar o `R` inferir o final com base  no começo, no tamanho do vetor e na frequência. Assim teríamos:

```
compras2 <- ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, data_ts_anual(dados_dia$DATA[1]),
               frequency =  365)
plot(compras2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o pacote `zoo` com os dados que você disponibilizou:

```
library(zoo)

plot(zoo(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, seq(from = as.Date("2018-07-19"), to = as.Date("2018-09-06"), by = 1)))
```

Se você reparar, nessa função, você pode informar de forma completa a sua data, Ano-Mês-Dia. Na função `ts` você informa um vetor de até dois dígitos então, acho mais fácil utilizar a função `zoo`.

O gráfico fica dessa forma, espero que seja o que você espera:

[image: Imgur]

Utilizando a função `ts` você deve modificar o ponto inicial `start` e sua frequência de tal forma que a mesma seja considerada em dias (como sugere os dados informados).

O 1º dia informado é 19/04/2018 - o 200º dia do ano, então: `start = c(2018, 200)` e de acordo com os detalhes da função `ts`, para dados diários, você pode utilizar o valor 7 na frequência (*The value of argument frequency is used when the series is sampled an integral number of times in each unit time interval. For example, one could use a value of 7 for frequency when the data are sampled daily*).

```
ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, start = c(2018,200), frequency = 7)
```

Comment: Olá. Eu testei sua sugestão, mas usando o `zoo` não consigo usar o `decompose`, acredito q como você comentou o `ts` trabalha com vetor... eu acho melhor trabalhar com `ts` mesmo, por que os próximos processos são do mesmo pacote. Eu acho que estou errando com o uso do `frequency` ou do período que estou escolhendo.

Comment: Eu estou com dificuldade em entender como as Séries Temporais funcionam.

Comment: acabei de atualizar a resposta utilizando a função `ts`

Comment: Olá! Eu testei aqui sua sugestão, mas não deu certo. Você consegue me mostrar exemplo prático?

Comment: o que não deu certo?

Comment: quando eu testei sua sugestão no `plot` mostrou uma série temporal de 2050 a 2070.

Comment: Sua questão era quanto ao gráfico (pelo que deu a entender), por isso utilizei o comando `zoo` que retorna um gráfico coerente. Quando você informou a questão de decompor a série, passa a ser um outro problema. Seus dados são diários, então pode-se pensar em usar `frequency = 365.25`, mas você não tem um ciclo completo, por isso do erro ao rodar `decompose(ts(..., frequency = 365.25))`. O `help` da função indica usar `frequency = 7` para dados diários, o que funciona quando se decompõe. Então, sugiro criar o gráfico com o `zoo` e decompor com `ts(..., frequency = 7)`

Comment: Entendi. Vou testar sua sugestão.